# Set contextmenu attribute by Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, contextmenu

How to set contextmenu attribute via Javascript?
I tried

```
someDiv.contextMenu = "menu_id";
```

but it don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setAttribute`

```
someDiv.setAttribute("contextMenu", "menu_id");
```